# Windows Update Stuck at 73%

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I was trying to update my windows version from 1809 to 22h2 and it still at 73%.When i reseted succesful my windows update and i need to update my windows above 2019 version and my windows recommend for me 22h2 and the downloading still ok but when I'm going to the Installing part and i Stuck at 73%

Comment: How long? It may take an hour or more.

Comment: @John it was more 1h exactly

Comment: @John i try use troubeshoot but i cannot repair

Comment: I posted a thorough answer for you to follow

Comment: At the worst, if after 5 or 6 hours it does not finish, download the Windows 10 22H2 ISO and reinstall, keeping your files. https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

> trying to update my windows version from 1809 to 22h2 and it still at
> 73%

If truly stuck, and your added comment indicates that, do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Normally Windows can update from a very old version, but if not, Repair Install will endeavor to fix all issues and bring you to the current version.

**1. In place Repair:**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**2. In place repair fails to update**

If Keep Everything does not work, then there is more serious operating system damage and / or the Windows User Profile is damaged.

In either case, back everything up and reinstall Windows. Then install Apps and recover your data.